# lxml -- how to change img src to absolute link

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, lxml, absolute-path

Using lxml, how do you globally replace all src attributes with an absolute link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after testing Mikko Ohtamaa's answer, here are some notes. 
it works for many tags and using the lxm, there are different situations, such as background-image:url(xxx). so I just use the regex to substitute.
here's the solution,

```
content = re.sub('(?P<left>("|\'))\s*(?P<url>(\w|\.)+(/.+?)+)\s*(?P<right>("|\'))',
                     '\g<left>' + url[:url.rfind('/')] + '/\g<url>\g<right>', content)
content = re.sub('(?P<left>("|\'))\s*(?P<url>(/.+?)+)\s*(?P<right>("|\'))',
                     '\g<left>' + url[:url.find('/', 8)] + '\g<url>\g<right>', content)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example code which also covers `<a href>`:

```
from lxml import etree, html
import urlparse

def fix_links(content, absolute_prefix):
    """
    Rewrite relative links to be absolute links based on certain URL.

    @param content: HTML snippet as a string
    """

    if type(content) == str:
        content = content.decode("utf-8")

    parser = etree.HTMLParser()

    content = content.strip()

    tree  = html.fragment_fromstring(content, create_parent=True)

    def join(base, url):
        """
        Join relative URL
        """
        if not (url.startswith("/") or "://" in url):
            return urlparse.urljoin(base, url)
        else:
            # Already absolute
            return url

    for node in tree.xpath('//*[@src]'):
        url = node.get('src')
        url = join(absolute_prefix, url)
        node.set('src', url)
    for node in tree.xpath('//*[@href]'):
        href = node.get('href')
        url = join(absolute_prefix, href)
        node.set('href', url)

    data =  etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=False, encoding="utf-8")

    return data
```

[The full story is available in Plone developer documentation](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/misc/html.html#rewriting-relative-links).

Comment: what is `parser = etree.HTMLParser() ` for?

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question but `HTMLParser` is a class and it constructs an instance of it.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure when this was added, but documents created from `lxml.fromstring()` now have a method called `make_links_absolute`. From the [documentation](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#working-with-links):

> make_links_absolute(base_href, resolve_base_href=True):
>
> This makes all links in the document absolute, assuming that base_href is the URL of the document. So if you pass base_href="http://localhost/foo/bar.html" and there is a link to baz.html that will be rewritten as http://localhost/foo/baz.html.
>
> If resolve_base_href is true, then any  tag will be taken into account (just calling self.resolve_base_href()).

Comment: It looks like you want to use `resolve_base_href` first to deal with base tags and then call `make_links_absolute`